# How to get SelectedItemId of BottomNavigationView in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-bottom-nav-view

I have implemented  BottomNavigationView in my app. Everything going easy and perfect but there is one problem i.e. on back press I want to get the currently active tab selected but now selected tab does not change when back press. Fragment changes but tab selection does not change. How can I detect the current tab and change the selected tab on back press. I tried a lot of things to do but not able to get selected tab ID.Please help.

**Code:**

```
      int i =   getSelectedItem(bottomNavigationView);
    Log.e("TAG", "onCreate:tab "+i );

      private int getSelectedItem(BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView){
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i=0;i<bottomNavigationView.getMenu().size();i++){
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(i);
        if (menuItem.isChecked()){
            return menuItem.getItemId();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: take a global variable for id and update it when your select the tab from BottomNavigationView. hence when you press back button it will give you last selected tab item id.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the checked item id, try this:

```
int checkedItemId = bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId();
```

To change current selected item, use this:

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.target_item_nemu).setChecked(true);
```

Comment: You want its position or menu id?

Comment: please share more code, where do you want to use it?

Comment: whatever I can get. Menu id or position. I just need to change tab selection on backpress. but i tried in oncreate and onresume both but not working

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to show home fragment in onBackPressed if another fragment is showing, else (if the home fragment is the currently showing), exit the app. Right?

Comment: no, i have four tabs a,b,c,d. if I selected d fragment then it will be selected. If i press back then it will go to c fragment but still d tab is selected. I want to c tab selected when back press. How can I ?

Comment: Do you use a ViewPager for managing Fragments? Or simply FragmentManager?

Comment: I have fragmentManager

Comment: I thing the problem is to check another item, not finding current checked item. In onBackPressed you can check visibility of fragments using `fragmentA.isVisible()`, then set state of related menu to checked (answer updated).